# html5 audio multiple play buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Im trying to display multiple play buttons, so if you click on play one, then the music starts but then if you click on the second play button then the music will play for the second one. At the moment, if one is playing and i click on the second one , it stops then i have to click it again.

How can i do this without it stoping when i click on another play button while the music is playing

Here is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/eD9K3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.player = document.getElementById('player');
    $('.play').click(function(){
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
            $('.play').html('Play');
            $(this).html('Pause');
        } else {
            player.pause();
            $('.play').html('Play');
            $(this).html('Play');
        }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning multiple play buttons to the same audio element. The audio is playing when you click the second one so it pauses and plays when it's clicked again (as your click handler states).

Make three different audio elements, one for each button and assign each play button's click handler to pause/play them separately.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $playButtons.length; i++) {
    var playButton = $playButtons[i];
    var player = $players[i];

    $(playButton).click(onPlayClick.bind(null, playButton, player));  
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eD9K3/1/